# Debian - File Permissions and umask

Tags: debian, file-permissions, debian-wheezy, umask

This might be a noob question, but here goes ^^:

I've just set up a debian wheezy server, and Installed laravel on it. Anyway, I'm having some trouble both as to what the file permissions should be, for laravel (files in general), so that they can read write and execute. Is this group? or is it a different user?

Also, once I figure out the appropriate set of file permissions for my `/var/` folder, how would I make it the default? Would that just be using umask.

I've tried umask before, and let's just say I ended up having to rebuilt the system :p

Hope someone can answer my questions

Comment: I recently did an app with Laravel on apache, and setup all files to be owned by apache:apache.   Whether or not that's the best way to do it, it does work.   I'm not really an apache/php guru, but I do at least know that the apache account on my machine is fairly restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try what the Laravel documentation says?

```
Permissions

Laravel requires one set of permissions to be configured - folders within app/storage require write access by the web server.
```

So if your using apache with mod_php, the directories and files inside this path should belong to the Apache user (usually www-data, apache or httpd depending on your distribution). If you're using PHP via fastcgi, php-fpm etc., the directories and files in this path should belong to the user executing PHP for this vhost.